# Can someone explain what this.value means in this example of code?

Tags: javascript, methods

I'm new to JavaScript and am still learning, I recently wrote this code and it works but I can't understand what this.value refers to in this instance:

```
function displayMatches() {
 const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cities); //what does this.value refer to?

 const html = matchArray.map(place => {

 const regex = new RegExp(this.value,'gi');

 const cityName = place.city.replace(regex,`<span class="hl">${this.value}
 </span>`);

 const stateName = place.state.replace(regex,`<span class="hl">${this.value}
 </span>`);

return `
<li>
  <span class="name">${place.city}, ${stateName}</span>
  <span class="population">${numberWithCommas(place.population)}</span>
</li>
`;
}).join ('');
suggestions.innerHtml = html;
}
```

I thought it was referring in wordsToMatch, here is all of the code:

```
const cities = [];
fetch(endpoint)
  .then(blob => blob.json())
  .then(data => cities.push(...data));

function findMatches(wordToMatch) {
  return cities.filter(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
    return place.city.match(regex) || place.state.match(regex)
  });
}

function displayMatches() {
  const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, cities);
  const html = matchArray.map(place => {
   const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
    const cityName = place.city.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    const stateName = place.state.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
return `
  <li>
    <span class="name">${cityName}, ${stateName}</span>
    <span class="population">${numberWithCommas(place.population)}</span>
  </li>
`;
  }).join('');
  suggestions.innerHTML = html;
}

const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);
```

Can anyone help explain this to my so I understand? Would really appreciate it! I find the whole .this() method still very confusing.

Comment: Because `displayMatches` is used as an event handler, the value of `this` when the function is invoked by the browser will be a reference to the DOM element involved with the event.

Comment: ...and `input` elements have a `value` property, so `this.value` accesses the `value` property of the input on which the event was hooked.

Comment: See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call some method binding some event **this** is the information what that event send to handler method. In this line of your code:

```
searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
```

You are listening the element searchInput then, in displayMatches() context **this** is the searchInput element.

That way this.value is searchInput.value.

Have you got it?

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up for me! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called. It refers to the DOM element which called the function. 
Let's say this is your JavaScript :

```
function alertMessage () {
    alert(this.value);
}
```

And this is your HTML :

```
<input type="text" onmousehover="alertMessage()" value="Test">
```

When the mouse will hover the input element JavaScript will alert "Test", because the value of the input with which you called the function is `Test`.